# Pyramid: how to set cookie without renderer?

Tags: python, pyramid

In configuration file:

```
config.add_route('lang', '/lang-{code}')
```

In views:

```
@view_config(route_name='lang')
def lang(request):
    code = request.matchdict['code']
    response = Response()
    response.set_cookie('lang', value=code, max_age=31536000) # max_age = year

    return HTTPFound(location=request.environ['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

The mechanism is simple: there is a dropped down menu item with languages and clicking on anyone must refresh site with new locale.

Runs without errors, but no cookie set up...
What I did wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

HTTPFound takes a headers parameter. Try something like `return HTTPFound(location='foo', headers=response.headers)`

Answer (score 13):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8746156/) is excellent. Another option is usage of the `HTTPFound` instance as a `Response`:

```
@view_config(route_name='lang')
def lang(request):
    code = request.matchdict['code']
    response = HTTPFound(location=request.environ['HTTP_REFERER'])
    response.set_cookie('lang', value=code, max_age=31536000) # max_age = year

    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Set cookie by using render_to_response

```
@view_config(route_name='index')  
def index_view(request):  
    lang = 'bn' 
    template = '../templates/index.jinja2'
    request.response.set_cookie('lang', lang) 
    return render_to_response(template, {'user_id':user_id}, request=request)
```