# get Cookie from HTTP request python

Tags: python

From what I've found with searches, Python seems incapable of this..

**Is it possible for a server written in Python to retrieve the Cookie header from an HTTP request, and if so, how?**

Specifically, the following header from the *request*:
Cookie: name=value; name2=value2

All of my searches so far seem to indicate that Python is only capable of acting as a client in regards to cookies.

Comment: Every web framework has a way to do this.  What are you using to build your server?

Comment: Python wouldn't be much of a programming language if it just "couldn't handle cookies", you should look into using frameworks or libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what framework you are using for the server as Ned mentioned.

If for example you are using [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) there is plenty of documentation to be found: http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/progguide/cookies.html

Check the documentation for whatever framework you are using to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely dependent on what you are using as your framework for setting up the HTTP listener.  If you haven't found a way within the library you are using, you need to look into the documentation.

Vanilla python `HTTPlib`, in the absence of any framework, uses `cookielib` to setup this functionality.

http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html

Other web frameworks like Flask and Django embed the data into global request/response objects

```
request.set_cookie({'foo':'bar')

response.cookie['foo']
```

The syntax in pyramid is slightly different, but still embeds on a response object:

[Pyramid: how to set cookie without renderer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746087/pyramid-how-to-set-cookie-without-renderer)

Comment: cookielib.CookieJar is only capable of acting as a client, according to the documentation.  I want something closer to  `request.cookie['foo']` and `response.set_cookie({'foo':'bar'})`

Comment: You're going to need to look into utilizing a server-side framework.  I really recommend Flask as an easy introduction: flask.pocoo.org.